# Are newline escapes accepted in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, newline

I was reading another stackoverflow question and puzzled here...

```
$query=" SELECT account.id, client.client_id\n"
    . " FROM account, client\n"
    . " WHERE account.id = 19";
```

Are those newline escapes ok in the query?

My question is:
  Is statement like `"selection * from student where \n \n \n id='10'"` error free?

Comment: The string in PHP will already contain the new line characters. If you want to pass `\n` to MySQL, either use `\\n` or single quotes instead.

Comment: so `"selection * from student where \n \n \n  id='10'"` is error free?

Comment: Provided you using php and using double quotes.

Comment: @on_ but why...? php or php librarie does something on it before passing to mysql engine?

Comment: It has nothing to do with mySQL actually, but rather with php. When you quote a string in double quotes and use \n or \r escape chars, php simply interpret them into special characters, namely a newline or carriage return. See here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. Therefore the above query is basically a query over 3 lines which mySQL accepts perfectly. Think of a script file for mySQL. Similar thing

Comment: @on_ this answers the question thanks...you may edit the answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks @pinkpanther, I have amended the answer to be much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newlines in your above example will have no effect on the query or result set for that matter.

It really has nothing to do with MySQL actually, but rather with PHP. When you quote a string in double quotes and use \n or \r escape chars, PHP simply interprets them into special characters, namely a newline or carriage return. php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php Therefore the above query is basically a query over 3 lines which MySQL accepts perfectly as something like:

```
SELECT account.id, client.client_id
FROM account, client
WHERE account.id = 19
```

Think of a script file where the query is over several lines of the file. Similar thing